# Tensorflow Independent distribution mathematics

Tags: tensorflow, distribution, probability-density, tensorflow-probability

I read about a function in tensorflow, which re-parametrizes number of independent distributions to give a probability distribution https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Independent
Unfortunately, there is no sufficient maths explanation of the problem. Can someone help to explain mathematically how its done, or give some references?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, it's just taking a few distributions, and *assuming* independence, you by definition have a new multivariate random variable with the inherited distribution (again, assuming independence).
The rest is just batch-dimension tricks...
The documentation you referenced actually *does* explain all this, as well as giving examples.